# How do I get functions to work in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm in the Minecraft snapshot 1.12-pre6, and I'm trying to get Functions to work. Within my functions folder, I have a folder called  "func" and then a function called test.mcfunction. Yet when I go ingame and type function func:test it says that the function is non existent. What am I doing wrong?

World:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6MN9o0KfAwiNVhRZl9VZy1KUHc

Edit: I did type /reload ingame.

Answer (score -3):

I don't know why, but functions only work in prerelease 1. They don't even work in the finished update. You'll have to switch to prerelease 1 to use them.